# The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

After Updating VS 2017 version to 15.8.2 and web jobs tools to version 10. I am facing this issue.

the same solution is working in other workstations with the same visual studio version

It is a sample service bus trigger function and queue name and connection string properly

Comment: If you're using the Functions V2 runtime, check the [known issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Azure-Functions-runtime-2.0-known-issues). "The runtime does not register 1.0 built in bindings and triggers by default. [...] (additional bindings may be registered using the new extensibility model)"

Comment: @rickvdbosch I have already installed that extension from NuGet 
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus -Version 3.0.0-beta8

Comment: @rickvdbosch Any Idea on how to reset entire Functions Dev Environment configurations in Visualstudio 2017

Comment: @IndrakiranReddy, how does your functions.json look? I am assuming you are using Functions 2.0

Answer (score 6):

run `func extensions install` on terminal if getting error locally, it works for me

Answer (score 3):

One thing that solved this issue for me recently was to update the extensions file to the newest "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version.

You can find the newest versions here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/

Comment: What's the difference between that and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus?

Answer (score 1):

If possible please have a try to [update the azure functions and webjob tools to latest version.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs)

I test it with Azure function(v2) servicebus via default servicebus trigger template, it works correctly on my side. My VS version is 15.8.4

[image]

Comment: I have all that updated and it doesn't work for me.